# Prototyping in C++

Tags: c++, function, prototyping

If I prototype a function above the main function in my code, do I have to include all parameters which have to be given? Is there a way how I can just prototype only the function, to save time, space and memory?

Here is the code where I came up with this question:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int allesinsekunden(int, int, int);

int main(){
    int stunden, minuten, sekunden;

    cout << "Stunden? \n";
    cin >> stunden;
    cout << "Minuten? \n";
    cin >> minuten;
    cout << "Sekunden= \n";
    cin >> sekunden;

    cout << "Alles in Sekunden= " << allesinsekunden(stunden, minuten, sekunden) << endl;
}

int allesinsekunden (int h, int m, int s) {
    int sec;

    sec=h*3600 + m*60 + s;

    return sec;

}
```

Comment: Yes, how else would overloads work?

Comment: What is *exactly* you think you "save"? Your question doesn't make any sense. You want to "save" time by avoid typing 10 characters? What about readability? Maintainability? This is obfuscation, nothing more.

Comment: When you begin programming you always think that not typing three parameters save time. You will quickly learn that the opposite is true — the saving is minimal (typing is fast!) and omitting crucial information will *always* come back to bite you later. So it will actually cost you time in the long run.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point!

Comment: Removing parameters from a declaration (prototype) would only save space in a text file.  If you are worried about development time, take a typing (keyboarding) class as well as software design classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"If I prototype a function above the main function in my code, do I have to include all parameters which have to be given?"*

Yes, otherwise the compiler doesn't know how your function is allowed to be called.
Functions can be overloaded in c++, which means functions with the same name may have different number and type of parameters. Such the name alone isn't distinct enough.

> *"Is there a way how I can just prototype only the function, to save time, space and memory?"*

No. Why do you think it would save any memory?

Comment: I think of every line I could save, memory was only a suggestion not a 100% fact I was sure about.

Answer (score 2):

No, because it would add ambiguity.  In C++ it's perfectly possible to have two completely different functions which differ only in the number and/or type of input arguments.  (Of course, in a well-written program what these functions do should be related.)  So you could have

```
int allesinsekunden(int, int, int)
{
//...
}
```

and

```
int allesinsekunden(int, int)
{
//...
}
```

If you tried to 'prototype' (declare) one of these with

```
int allesinsekunden;
```

how would the compiler know which function was being declared?  Specifically how would it be able to find the right definition for use in `main`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the full signature of your function, i.e. the name, the return value, all parameters with types, their constness, etc.