# Prototyping in C/C++

Tags: c++, prototype

I am trying to create the prototype and write the function called average.

I am not sure how to create it, what  have gets the errors too few arguments to function..... on both lazlo and pietra

Average receives an array of student test scores.

average computes the average of the student’s scores

how do i properly create the prototype?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double average( int array[], int items); // function declaration (prototype)

int main()
{
    int lazlo[] = {90, 80, 85, 75, 65, -10};
    int pietra[] = { 100, 89, 83, 96, 98, 72, 78, -1};
    int num;

    num = average( lazlo );
    cout << "lazlo took " << num << "tests. Average: " << lazlo[ num ] << endl;

    num = average( pietra );
    cout << "pietra took " << num << "test. Average: " << pietra[ num ] << endl;

    // function call to average

}
```

Comment: You say you _tried_ to create it....so what happened? Did it fail? Are you unsure if you're doing it correctly. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: This is C++.  There is no such language as C/C++.

Comment: The function declaration you have is valid.    The way in which `main()` is calling the function is not consistent with the declaration (passing one argument instead of two, return value of `double` stored in an `int`).  You have also not defined (i.e. implemented) the function in code you have shown.

Comment: C is not a programming language? as far as i know you can use function declaration (prototyping) in both C and C++ @aschepler

Comment: C and C++ are difference languages. C/C++ is not a language that currently exists and is typically used by people who are completely confused about which language they are actually using.

Comment: Where is the function being implemented?

Comment: I am not even sure how to prototype let alone implement it @Ben

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207173/prototyping-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `average` to take two arguments: (a pointer to the first element of) an array and the number of items in the array.  The problem is that when you call `average` you only pass it one argument: the array (which decays into a pointer to its first element).  You're missing the `items` argument.

Your call should look something like this:

```
num = average(lazlo, 6);
```

The messages you print afterward are also incorrect.  `average` returns the average value, so `num` will be the average of the numbers in your array, not the number of items.  Additionally `lazlo[num]` will be an error, since `num` will be `64`, and there is no 64th item in your `lazlo` array.

Comment: I am aware.  I was trying to avoid bringing that up to someone who's just beginning to learn the language, as it can be a confusing topic.  I've edited the answer now that these comments brought it up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an actual function associated with the prototype in order for your code to work.  You can add this below your main function:

```
double average( int array[], int items) {
  // write your averaging code here
}
```

Once you have finished coding the average function, make sure to call it such that the number of inputs and datatypes match your prototype:

```
num = average(lazlo, 6);
num = average(pietra, 8);
```

Comment: "make sure to call it such that the number of inputs and datatypes match your prototype". Obviously he doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: yeah, but the other comments/answers address that.

Comment: An answer should try to be complete on its own.